# Prove that $QS$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$, $U\subseteq V$ a subspace, $S$ a positive operator on $V$ and $Q$ an orthogonal projection onto $U$. Show that $QS$ is diagonalizable.

Proof : Since $Q$ is an orthogonal projection, $Q=Q^*=Q^t$. Since $S$ is positive, it has a positive square root $S^{1/2}$, and because $S^{1/2}$ is positive, it is invertible. So $QS=S^{-1}SPS=S^{-1/2}S^{-1/2}S^{1/2}S^{1/2}QS^{1/2}S^{1/2}=S^{-1/2}(S^{1/2}QS^{1/2})S^{1/2}$. So $QS$ is similar to $S^{1/2}QS^{1/2}$. Since $(S^{1/2}QS^{1/2})^*=S^{1/2}Q^*S^{1/2}=S^{1/2}QS^{1/2}$, this operator is self-adjoint and hence diagonalizable. Since $QS$ is similar to $S^{1/2}QS^{1/2}$, it is also diagonalizable.

Does this argument look ok? Also, does anyone see perhaps an alternative way to approach this problem. At first glance, my suspicion was to show that $Q$ and $S$ commute, so they'd be simultaneously diagonalizable. $S$ has a spectral resolution $S=\sum_i\lambda_iQ_i$, so it'd be enough to show $QQ_i=Q_iQ$ for each $i$, but I wasn't sure if this was true.